# Are there rampart craters elsewhere in the Solar System?

Tags: crater

[Rampart craters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rampart_crater) are impact craters with fluidized ejecta. These are mostly found on Mars, and there is one on Earth (Ries crater). Have rampart craters been found on any other Solar System bodies? Perhaps on a moon of Jupiter or Saturn?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are some rampart craters [on Earth](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/books/book/2312/chapter/130244719/Rampart-craters-on-Earth):

- Ries crater in Germany,
- Bosumtwi crater in Ghana,
- Tenoumer crater in Mauritania,
- Lonar crater in India, and
- Meteor crater in the United States

Additionally, a number of rampart craters have been discovered [on Ganymede](http://www2.ess.ucla.edu/%7Ejewitt/class/Surfaces_Papers/Boyce_10.pdf) and Europa.

> ... the mere existence of these craters on Ganymede and Europa suggests that an atmosphere is not required for ejecta fluidization, nor can ejecta fluidization be explained by the flow of dry ejecta. Moreover, the absence of fluidized ejecta on other icy bodies suggests that abundant volatiles in the target also may not be the sole cause of ejecta fluidization. The
> restriction of these craters to the grooved terrain of Ganymede ...

Also, [this reference](http://www.marscraterconsortium.nau.edu/Boyce1MCC10.pdf).

[Ceres](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/news/505/side-by-side-earth-vs-dwarf-planet-ceres/) **does not** have rampart crater, but it has craters, such as Haulani, that have flow features in their ejecta blankets.

Comment: Ganymede: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1945-5100.2010.01044.x